# Does this non-parametric test have a name?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, ordinal-data

I have a single ordinal sample, where there are five possible scores (1-5). Most of the scores are the middle value (3), so tests of the median are no use to me.

I am interested in the other scores: those in {1,2} and {4,5}.

I can count

- x = the number in {1,2}
- n = the number in {1,2,4,5}

and do a binomial test with success probability of 0.5 (which gives me a very low p value - great).

Does this test have a name?

Comment: Names often vary between disciplines but I would have called this the binomial test.

Comment: R calls it the binomial test, but lots of intro books call it the sign test.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the *sign test*, where you test the proportion above (or below) the median value, regardless of magnitude.

For more information, see *Introduction to Probability and Statistics* by Milton and Arnold.

Comment: Just one clarification: when I've read about the sign test (e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test#Example_of_sign_test_for_median_of_a_single_sample)), the binomial bit has always used the total number in the sample as n (but the examples have never had most of the data being the median value). But it's still a sign test if I want strictly above and strictly below, and I use n = |{scores above}|+|{scores below}|? I haven't got easy access to the textbook you mention to clarify.

Comment: @PurpleCoat: yep, still is the sign test. Basically it's quite a destructive test, as it literally uses only the + and - signs (no magnitude, no zeroes).